# Eclipse, PyDev Syntax Coloring

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

In Preferences-PyDev-Editor-"Appearance Color Options" I can edit colors. I can edit the color of "keywords" for instance. Is there a way to edit color of a specific keyword, say "range"?

Comment: I just tried to find an option to specify a color for a certain keyword, but it seems that this feature is not supported, or at least I could not find out how to set it^^

Comment: No, and I doubt many users would want this. Do you have a specific need? (e.g. separately highlighting 3.x keywords?)

Comment: @smci I beg to differ, I'd love to be able to slightly change the color of the keyword 'class' (for example.) It would be nice to be able to quickly identify it among any other keyword.

Comment: Ok, that's a fair use case. Another one would be deprecated keywords. I was wondering if the OP's intent was to see 2-to-3 syntax differences.

Answer (score 3):

There's currently no such feature (i.e.: the keywords are all 'hardcoded' to a single color).

If you fell that this is really needed, please create a feature request explaining your use-case in the pydev tracker. (see: http://pydev.org/about.html)

Comment: ...with a compelling use-case or two. I think highlighting deprecated keywords could be a good one.